# when i read string which consists of backslash,but in run time its taking as double black slash and because of java is throwing exception:

Tags: java, date, datetime-format

Below string i am reading from excel file.

```
String s1 = "EEEE d \u0027de\u0027 MMMMM \u0027de\u0027 yyyy";
```

but when i pass string to below date Time format method getting

```
selectText = new SimpleDateFormat(s1,lc).format(getCurrentdate());
```

getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'e'
exception.
```

Please help I need String to be read same as original and also want to keep  .

```
String s1 = "EEEE d \u0027de\u0027 MMMMM \u0027de\u0027 yyyy";
String expecteddate = selectText.format(getCurrentdate());
```

Comment: I tried cleaning up the code cause it seemed like a lot of typos.

Comment: That format string does not generate any exceptions for me.  Please edit your question and make sure that you are showing us the format string which you are actually using.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. Your code runs nicely here and produces a string like `jueves 28 de marzo de 2019`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For example `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("es-ES")))` produces `jueves, 28 de marzo de 2019`.